# I made a Welcomer bot using discord.py. It starts successfully, but does not send the specified message to the channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a Welcomer bot using discord.py. It starts successfully, but does not send the specified message to the channel. Why is this?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import datetime
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    emb = discord.Embed(
        color = 0xff0000,
        title = "{member.name}, welcome to my server!",
        description = f"Total participants: {len(list(member.guild.members))}",
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    )
    
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL ID)
    await channel.send(embed = emb)

bot.run ("BOT TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has no issue in it. I suspect the intents are turned off. Go to [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/), and turn on **Server Members Intent** in your bot application.

[image]

`on_member_join` event doesn't execute without this intent turned off.

Edit:

Also try defining the intents in the code:

```
import discord
#....
from discord import Intents
intents = Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents = intents)
```